# python 2.7 :unicode object, not in method

Tags: python-2.7

Following is my intention
1. read json file with codecs and utf-8 encoding 
2. load the json file into python as dictionary 
3. iterate through dictionary , if 'categories' key contains   value 'Restaurant' then add it to a set ; else continue to next iteration.

Issue: 'categories' key may contain values like 'Restaurant', 'Restaurant and Bristro', 'Restaurant and Bar'. 
My if condition should select all these three values not only 'Restaurant'

Sample code as follows

```
import json
restaurant_ids = set()
# open the json file
with codecs.open(json_file.json, encoding='utf_8') as f:

    # iterate through each line (json record) in the file
    for b_json in f:

        # convert the json record to a Python dict
        business = json.loads(b_json)

        # if this key is not a restaurant, skip to the next one
        if u'Restaurants' not in business[u'categories']:
            continue
        # add the restaurant business id to our restaurant_ids set
        restaurant_ids.add(business[u'business_id'])

print (len(restaurant_ids))
```

I am getting error at if condition, business[u'categories'] seems to be unicode object, I get following error

```
Argument of type 'NonType' is not  iterable
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Print the value of business[u”categories”] is it a list/iterable?

Comment: business[u'categories'] is an unicode object

Comment: So it isn’t iterable, so you get the error. One of your lines doesn’t have a categories list, or it’s empty - so count the lines as you read them and print the line number with the error then you know where to look. You might need to exclude that line, or make your code only iterate on the categories if categories is a list.

Answer (score 0):

One of the JSON objects is missing the `catagories` key.